# how pass parameter from IsAuthorized to HandleUnauthorizedRequest Method web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, authorize-attribute

I extended `AuthorizeAttribute` and based on some condition I want display different messages and httpStatusCode to the user. My code is:

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    string headerApiKeyValue = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<string> headerValues;
        bool isExitsInHeader = actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("ApiKey",out headerValues);

        if (!isExitsInHeader || headerValues == null)
        {
            actionContext.Response = CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, apiKeyNotExistInHeader);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // log exception [apiKeyValue]
        return false;
    }
}

protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{        
    string a = actionContext.Request.ToString();
    // log here
    actionContext.Response = CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed, accessDeniedMessage);
}
```

In above code there is two response types: First is when the key dos not exist in the header and the second is `IsAuthorized` method throw exception. How to handle this two types of messages in `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method? Is there any way to pass parameter to this method?

Comment: You really should prove read your questions and try to use the correct grammar. It is really hard to follow your train of thoughts along, if one can not decypher, where one sentence starts and the other ends. I tried my best to rectify this.

Answer (score 1):

*update: (I just realized this question is almost 2 years old by now, so I don't assume, we'll here back from the op)*

You can just use a private field to store any information you need. Here is a really dead simple example demonstrating this:

```
public class HeaderAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private bool invalidApiKey = false;

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        bool isExitsInHeader = actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("ApiKey", out IEnumerable<string> headerValues);

        if (isExitsInHeader && headerValues.Any(x => x.Contains("foo")))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (isExitsInHeader && !headerValues.Any(x => x.Contains("foo")))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            invalidApiKey = true;
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //check if response has header indicating invalid api key
        if (invalidApiKey)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed,
                Content = new StringContent("errorMessage here")
            };

        }
        else
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
                Content = new StringContent("someOther message here")
            };
        }
        // log here
    }
}
```

What this does (and it is not really a real world example) is the following:

1. Check if the header "ApiKey" is present
2. If it is and any of those results is "foo", we're golden
3. If it is, but no value is "foo", return false
4. If no header is present, set the invalid header field to true and return false

The `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` then just checks if this private field is set or not and uses it as a switch to return different `HttpResponseMessages` with different Status Codes to the user.

In the end you onjly need to implement your logic to validate the api Key and return the appropriate messages as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

Try this & pass the exception you want

Comment: I don't think, that this is a good way to go, since this method is either returning true or false and throwing an exception, just as a means to have some additional control flow is bad practice.